Which time zone are the statistics based on to calculate badges?
eg for the "Suffrage" badge ("Used 30 votes in a day"), when does the day start?
(Alternatively, it could be based on a rolling 24hrs, but I doubt it because that would seem unnecessarily complicated!)

I believe it starts at 0:00 GMT. To find out if that is correct for you, try voting 30 times and see what message you get. It should specify the time until you can vote again, +-1 hour. Check back again around then and see how many minutes until you can vote again and there's your answer.

Stack Exchange runs on UTC time.  You can see this by hovering over your name at the top of the page - the time is at the bottom of the  profile popup.
